# C Language function called with few arguments, but not error?

Tags: c

In the following C code, function `printr` called only with one parameter, But all compiled with no warning on GCC and VS.
I am confused why this is OK? Thanks!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int printr(i, j){
    printf("The first parameter %d\n", i);
    printf("The second parameter %d\n", j);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    printr(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try using a prototype: `int printr(int i, int j) { /* ... */ }`. You are using old-stye function definition

Comment: It's a duplicate, I've seen this question before, but I don't have a link.

Comment: @pmg This looks rather like implicit int; old-style would be empty parentheses instead of void or somesuch.

Comment: @Jens: whatever it is, it is **NOT** a prototype :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `printr()` by using old-fashion function definition syntax, therefore compiler cannot do some syntactic check. You should define it like this:

```
int printr(int i, int j) {
```

By the way, with `-Wextra`, `gcc` will give warnings about your definition.

Answer (score 3):

Gcc **does** warn you:

```
$ gcc -Wextra y.c
y.c: In function ‘printr’:
y.c:4: warning: type of ‘i’ defaults to ‘int’
y.c:4: warning: type of ‘j’ defaults to ‘int’
```

And once you've fixed those it will warn

```
y.c: In function ‘main’:
y.c:11: error: too few arguments to function ‘printr’
```